# PHP Countdown added two hours

Tags: php, datetime, time, countdown

```
currentime=strtotime('22:00:00');
rem=currentime - strtotime('now'); //now is 20:00:00
remaining=date("H:i:s",rem);
```

My problem is, remaining shows `04:00:00` instead of `02:00:00`

Is there any clue why it is? I also set `date_default_timezone_set`

Comment: Have you checked Php.ini for the time setup?

Comment: there is nothing related to time setup

Comment: date.timezone , as Evaldas says below.

Comment: please `echo date("H:i:s",strtotime('now'));` and confirm it's 20:00:00 (or thereabouts)

Comment: i confirm that it shows our current time.

Comment: Have you tried to echo date_default_timezone_get() ?
As well try to output all of the values - currentime, strtotime('22:00:00'), strtotime('now'), rem

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings in php.ini file. There should be line similar to this one:
date.timezone = UTC

Try setting it to your time zone.

Comment: i set date.timezone to my time zone in php.ini file but there is no change.

Comment: Have you restarted your apache server? Changes in ini file will not be reflected before the next start of apache.

Comment: i cannot do that, i'm using web hosting.